# Not understanding the meaning of a logic question.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to understand the meaning of this exercise question in a logic textbook.

> For each of the following statement forms,find a statement form that is logically equivalent to its negation and in which negation signs apply only to statement letters.
> i. $A \rightarrow ( B \leftrightarrow \lnot C )$ 
> ii. $\lnot A \lor ( B \rightarrow  C )$ 
> iii. $A \land (B \lor \lnot C)$

But I keep failing. I don't understand  the part "*find a statement form that is logically equivalent to its negation and in which negation signs apply only to statement letters*". So I am unable to solve it.Can someone tell me what that means?

Comment: It believe it means that negations should not appear outside non-atomic formulas, for example $\neg(A\wedge B)$ should be written as $(\neg A)\vee (\neg B)$.

Comment: Case ii: by [Materila Implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) is equivalent to: $\lnot A \lor \lnot B \lor C$. And so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each problem you have a statement form $\varphi$; you are to start with its negation $\neg\varphi$ and use logical equivalences to transform that into a statement form in which no compound expression is negated: the only expressions that are preceded by a negation are individual statement letters. As **Couchy** said in the comments, you cannot have $\neg(A\land B)$, because in it the compound expression $A\land B$ is negated, but you can apply De Morgan’s laws to convert that to $\neg A\lor\neg B$, in which the only things negated are the statement letters $A$ and $B$. I’ll work the first one in gory detail as an example.

$$\begin{align*}
\neg\big(A\to(B\leftrightarrow\neg C)\big)&\equiv\neg\big(\neg A\lor(B\leftrightarrow\neg C)\big)\\
&\equiv\neg(\neg A)\land\neg(B\leftrightarrow\neg C)\\
&\equiv A\land\neg(B\leftrightarrow\neg C)\\
&\equiv A\land\neg\big((B\land\neg C)\lor(\neg B\land \neg(\neg C))\big)\\
&\equiv A\land\neg\big((B\land\neg C)\lor(\neg B\land C)\big)\\
&\equiv A\land\big(\neg(B\land\neg C)\land\neg(\neg B\land C)\big)\\
&\equiv A\land\neg(B\land\neg C)\land\neg(\neg B\land C)\\
&\equiv A\land\big(\neg B\lor\neg(\neg C)\big)\land\big(\neg(\neg B)\lor\neg C\big)\\
&\equiv A\land(\neg B\lor C)\land(B\lor\neg C)
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

It means you are only using $\neg$ in front of $A$ $B$ or $C$. So instead of writing $\neg(A \lor B)$, for example, you would write $\neg A \land \neg B$